# Question on $x$-section of measurable rectangle in product measure space $X \times Y$

Tags: analysis, measure-theory

I'm reviewing my analysis notes.  We have that $(X, \Sigma, \mu)$ and $(Y, \tau, \nu)$ are complete measure spaces.  We are considering the product measure space $(X \times Y, \Sigma(\lambda^{*}), \lambda)$.

Basically, if $R = A \times B$, where $A \in \Sigma$ and $B \in \tau$, we define the $x$-section of $R$ as $$R_{x} = \{ y \in B \mid (x, y) \in A \times B \}.$$

If we consider $F$ to be a union of these $R$'s (i.e., $F = \bigcup \limits_{j = 1}^{\infty} R_{j}$), then my professor defines $F_{x} = \bigcup \limits_{j = 1}^{\infty} ((A_{j} \times B_{j})_{x})$.

Now, I think $\bigcup \limits_{j = 1}^{\infty} ((A_{j} \times B_{j})_{x})$ should be equal to $\bigcup \limits_{j = 1}^{\infty} B_{j}$, but in the notes, we have it equal to $\bigcup \limits_{x \in A_{j}} B_{j}$.  I'm not even sure what this union over $x \in A_{j}$ means in this context, let alone why it is equal to our $x$-section.  Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So $R_j=A_j \times B_j$ presumably.

It is not true in general that

$\bigcup \limits_{j = 1}^{\infty} ((A_{j} \times B_{j})_{x})=\bigcup \limits_{j = 1}^{\infty} B_{j}$,

take for example $x \notin A_j$ for all $j$, then $(A_j \times B_j)_x$ is empty for all $j$ and so will be their union.

Now lets show that $\bigcup_{j=1}^{\infty} (A_j \times B_j)_x = \bigcup_{x \in A_j} B_j $.

You are right that the notation of the RHS is a bit vague but it probably means $F_x=\bigcup_{j \in \mathbb{N}: x \in A_j} B_j$, which makes sense since otherwise $(A_j \times B_j)_x$ is empty.

Now let $y \in F_x$, then $ y \in (A_i \times B_i)_x$ for some $i \in \mathbb{N}$, this means that $x \in A_i$, and $y \in B_i$. So $y \in \bigcup_{x \in A_j} B_j$.

Let $y \in \bigcup_{x \in A_j} B_j$, then $y \in B_i$ for some $i \in \mathbb{N}$ and $x \in A_i$, therefore $y \in (A_i \times B_i)_x$ which implies $y \in F_x$

Comment: Does it make sense to talk about an $x$-section for $x \in \emptyset$?  That threw me off.

Comment: Oh right, probably not, that is a bad counterexample I guess, let me think of something better.

Comment: Also, $F_{x}$ is the $x$-section for a particular $x \in Aj$.  Why then does the right hand side union over all $x \in A_{j}$?

Comment: In the definition of $R_x$ or $F_x$ it is not required that $x \in A_j$ for any $j$, so this provides a counterexample. For your second comment, I edited the definition to be more precise

Comment: Oooohhhh...first of all, your example was excellent.  I was only considering $x \in A_{j}$, but the $x$ could come from anywhere (although I think your statement about $A_{j} \times B_{j}$ being empty is a bit off -- I understood the point, though).

Comment: Second of all, I was misinterpreting the union to be over all $x \in A_{j}$, but what you said makes perfect sense.  It is the union over all $A_{j}$ such that $x \in A_{j}$.